# Rectangular Selector does not save previously selected values

Tags: python, matplotlib-widget

I am trying to make the basic rectangular selection (matplotlib) in python, but with results being appended instead of being updated. Right now, if I draw a rectangle, it selects the points in the area, but that's it. If I select a rectangle elsewhere, the points from the previous rectangular selection disappears. 
Please let me know how to append the selections such that the previous selections do not disappear. Instead, all the selections are plotted. 
PS - Adding it to a key function to add, remove and modify the selections would be excellent, but the basic requirement is just to add/remove.
Thanks for your help. 
Adarsh

Code Given below -

```
from __future__ import print_function
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xdata = np.linspace(0,9*np.pi, num=301)
ydata = np.sin(xdata)*np.cos(xdata*2.4)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(xdata, ydata)
point, = ax.plot([],[], marker="o", color="crimson")
text = ax.text(0,0,"")

def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    'eclick and erelease are the press and release events'
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    mask = (xdata > min(x1,x2)) & (xdata < max(x1,x2)) & (ydata > min(y1,y2)) & (ydata < max(y1,y2))    
    xmasked =xdata[mask]
    ymasked =ydata[mask]
    line6.set_data(xmasked, ymasked)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    return
def toggle_selector(event):     
    print(' Key pressed.')
    if event.key in ['Q', 'q'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector deactivated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
    if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector activated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)

toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(ax,
    line_select_callback,
    drawtype='box',
    useblit=False,
    button=[1, 3],  # don't use middle button
    minspanx=5,
    minspany=5,
    spancoords='pixels',
    interactive=True)
line6, = ax.plot([],[], 'yo')
plt.connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can anyone please help?